# Sort dead hyperlinks in Excel with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, hyperlink

The title says it:

I have an excel Sheet with an column full of hyperlinks. Now I want that an VBA Script checks which hyperlinks are dead or work and makes an entry into the next columns either with the text 404 Error or active.

Hopefully someone can help me because I am not really good at VB.

EDIT:

I found @ http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/printthread.php?Cat=&Board=84&main=1037294&type=thread

A solution which is made for word but the Problem is that I need this solution for Excel. Can someone translate this to Excel solution?

```
Private Sub testHyperlinks()
    Dim thisHyperlink As Hyperlink
    For Each thisHyperlink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        If thisHyperlink.Address <> "" And Left(thisHyperlink.Address, 6) <> "mailto" Then
            If Not IsURLGood(thisHyperlink.Address) Then
                Debug.Print thisHyperlink.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Function IsURLGood(url As String) As Boolean
    ' Test the URL to see if it is good
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest

    On Error GoTo IsURLGoodError
    request.Open "GET", url
    request.Send
    If request.Status = 200 Then
        IsURLGood = True
    Else
        IsURLGood = False
    End If
    Exit Function
IsURLGoodError:
        IsURLGood = False
End Function
```

Comment: Above answers are good, but I'd use caution, querying a ton of urls (over 9000) without some sort of delay can cause problems for your dns, as I found out the hard way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First add a reference to Microsoft XML V3 (or above), using Tools->References. Then paste this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckHyperlinks()

    Dim oColumn As Range
    Set oColumn = GetColumn() ' replace this with code to get the relevant column

    Dim oCell As Range
    For Each oCell In oColumn.Cells

        If oCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then

            Dim oHyperlink As Hyperlink
            Set oHyperlink = oCell.Hyperlinks(1) ' I assume only 1 hyperlink per cell

            Dim strResult As String
            strResult = GetResult(oHyperlink.Address)

            oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strResult

        End If

    Next oCell


End Sub

Private Function GetResult(ByVal strUrl As String) As String

    On Error Goto ErrorHandler

    Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30

    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.send

    GetResult = oHttp.Status & " " & oHttp.statusText

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    GetResult = "Error: " & Err.Description

End Function

Private Function GetColumn() As Range
    Set GetColumn = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete solution!

I have just one problem, somehow the script won't do anything I even went into step-by-step mode (F8) and see that the script doesn't go through the "If oCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then" loop. It goes just directly to the "End If" expression loops so on.

How should I interpret such an behavior?

Comment: @elhombre, are you sure that it's looking at the correct cells? My example code just looks at column A in the first worksheet of the active workbook. Also, I was assuming that when you said you had "a column full of hyperlinks" that you meant a column where the cells were actual clickable Excel hyperlinks. If you just meant that the cell values were URLs, then you can strip out all the code from the If to the End If and replace it with... (see next comment)

Comment: [continued]
If Trim(oCell.Value) <> "" Then
    oCell.Offset(0,1).Value = GetResult(oCell.Value)
End If

Comment: You assumed right! These are clickable cells with hyperlinks which open the Site destination in the Internet explorer. I will look if it's checking the wrong cell

Comment: sorry had to sort it out manually. But I think your answer is correct

Comment: +1 very nicely done. Probably easier though to use late binding that have users setting references.

Answer (score 12):

Gary's code is perfect, but I would rather use a public function in a module and use it in a cell as function. The advantage is that you can use it in a cell of your choice or anyother more complex function.

In the code below I have adjusted Gary's code to return a boolean and you can then use this output in an =IF(CHECKHYPERLINK(A1);"OK";"FAILED"). Alternatively you could return an Integer and return the status itself (eg.: =IF(CHECKHYPERLINK(A1)=200;"OK";"FAILED"))

A1: http://www.whatever.com
A2: =IF(CHECKHYPERLINK(A1);"OK";"FAILED")

To use this code please follow Gary's instructions and additionally add a module to the workbook (right click on the VBAProject --> Insert --> Module) and paste the code into the module.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CheckHyperlink(ByVal strUrl As String) As Boolean

    Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.send

    If Not oHttp.Status = 200 Then CheckHyperlink = False Else CheckHyperlink = True

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    CheckHyperlink = False
End Function
```

Please also be aware that, if the page is down, the timeout can be long.

Comment: It complained about semicolons in the if statement you wrote. Did you mean to use commas?

Comment: I think it depends on the language version of Excel you are using (or maybe the locale?)

Comment: @Dynamicbyte: I'm trying to add your code to Excel 2013 (why would I still need Gary's code btw?), but when compiling I get the error `User-defined type not defined` on this line `oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30`...any ideas? Is it because I have not added a reference to Microsoft XML V3? And if so, I tried looking how to do that, but can't find that either...:s Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Flo: to add the reference when you have the VBA panel open, click in Tools, Reference, and then scroll down until you find Microsoft XML V3