# List Hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I ahve an Excel work book containing a large number of sheets. Each sheet has between 1 and 12 Hyperlinks to different documents on a website. These dicuments are updated from time to time. I would like a macro that lists all the Hyperlinks in a new sheet but also lists the sheet name next to each link. I have the following that lists the Hyperlinks and the cell ref

```
Sub CopyHyperLinks()  
  Dim rCell As Range 
  Dim ws As Worksheet 
  Dim Lhyper As Long                  
  On Error Resume Next 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
  Sheets("Hypers").Delete 
  On Error Goto 0 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
  Sheets.Add().Name = "Hypers" 

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Hypers" Then 
      For Lhyper = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Hyperlinks.Count  
        ws.Hyperlinks(Lhyper).Range.Copy 
        With Sheets("Hypers").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up)  
          .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
          .Offset(1, 1) = ws.Hyperlinks(Lhyper).Range.Address 
        End
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 
       Next Lhyper 
     End If 
  Next ws 
End Sub
```

How can i modify this to show the sheet name instead of the cell ref. 
is it also possible to then check that these Hyperlinks are valid destinations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the name of the worksheet of the hyperlink with this line:

```
ws.Hyperlinks(Lhyper)..Range.Worksheet.Name
```

Here's is your reworked code (it contained some other syntactical errors that I corrected):

```
Sub CopyHyperLinks()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lhyper As Long
    Dim rngLink As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Hypers").Delete

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Sheets.Add().Name = "Hypers"

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Hypers" Then
            For Lhyper = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Hyperlinks.Count
                Set rngLink = ws.Hyperlinks(Lhyper).Range
                rngLink.Copy
                With Sheets("Hypers").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                    .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                    .Offset(1, 1) = rngLink.Address
                    .Offset(1, 2) = rngLink.Worksheet.Name
                    .Offset(1, 3) = CheckHyperlink(ws.Hyperlinks(Lhyper).Address)
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Next Lhyper
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

If you want to verify the links, include the code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118221/sort-dead-hyperlinks-in-excel-with-vba). Include this line in your code:

```
.Offset(1, 3) = CheckHyperlink(ws.Hyperlinks(Lhyper).Address)
```

and also this routine:

```
Public Function CheckHyperlink(ByVal strUrl As String) As Boolean

    Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.send

    If Not oHttp.Status = 200 Then CheckHyperlink = False Else CheckHyperlink = True

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    CheckHyperlink = False
End Function
```

You need to include a reference to the "Microsoft XML" library in your VBA project.

Comment: +1 good full answer + never seen this xml reference before - it look interesting

Comment: very helpful library, makes life a lot easier when you have to handle XML (e.g. for ribbons or external data) or HTTP

Comment: Peter i have this working now.  It is just what i need thank you so much.
 
Just a couple of little things
 
1) It picks up the Hyperlink on the very first sheet however it doesn't give the sheet name or true/false for the verification.
 
2) When pasting is it possible to format the way it pastes so it all pastes the same ie column A Hyperlink (just stretch column A to fit text rather than pasting as the merged cell some of the Hyperlinks are) Column B Sheet Name (again stretched to fit the text) Column C True/False.
 
I cant post my workbook as I am MOD and it contains RESTRICTED info sorry.

Comment: 1) don't know, hard to judge without the file. try debugging the code by stepping though it with F8 and looking into the Locals and Watch window! 2) Run `Sheets("Hypers").Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit` as the last command before `End Sub`. PS: Don't forget to mark it as the answer! ;-)

Comment: Thanks  that works a bit better. I have a problem now when i update the Hyperlink if it gave a false when verifying. I run the macro again to ensure it gives a true and it duplicates the Hyperlink giving one a false as before and one as a true showing it is now updated. How do i stop it still showing the old False result.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce, but couldn't. when i updated a link in excel, I could not get a reference to the old one in VBA. Don't know what happens here... :-(

Comment: Would the XML Library that i reference make a difference? I added Microsoft XML v 6.0.

Comment: v6 certainly works as it is the latest to my knowledge. But even the old versions should have this functionality...

Comment: I have added back in the line that gives th cell reference to see where it is pulling the old link from and i get for example $E$6 for the old link and $E$6:$E$6 for the new updated link.

Comment: I went through the hyperlinks and re-linked the ones that were duplicating. All is good now. Still not picking up the very first sheets sheet name or verifying the link for some reason.

Comment: Next mission is to get all the false links to highlight the whole row red.