# Checking for broken hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, hyperlink

I have a large list of hyperlinks (plus a few cells of nonsense) that I need to check. I need to know which links are still active and which no longer exist or return a 404 (or other) Error. I have been using the advice in this entry: [Sort dead hyperlinks in Excel with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118221/sort-dead-hyperlinks-in-excel-with-vba) and it worked great in a small selection of links, some of which I deliberately broke myself. However, now that I try to use the same macro on my actual list of hyperlinks it won't work at all! I've manually checked a few and have found links with 404 errors. Again, when I deliberately mistype one of the addresses it will pick that up but it won't pick up any in the list that were broken already.

I'm totally new to macros and am really stumbling about in the dark here. Any help/advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I've been using this for a while and it has been working for me.

```
Sub Audit_WorkSheet_For_Broken_Links()

If MsgBox("Is the Active Sheet a Sheet with Hyperlinks You Would Like to Check?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then

    Exit Sub

End If

On Error Resume Next
For Each alink In Cells.Hyperlinks
    strURL = alink.Address

    If Left(strURL, 4) <> "http" Then
        strURL = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Hyperlink Base") & strURL
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = "Testing Link: " & strURL
    Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objhttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
    objhttp.Send

    If objhttp.statustext <> "OK" Then

        alink.Parent.Interior.Color = 255
    End If

Next alink
Application.StatusBar = False
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox ("Checking Complete!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Cells With Broken or Suspect Links are Highlighted in RED.")

End Sub
```

Comment: I keep getting `alink` is not defined.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Then add `Dim alink as Hyperlink` before the loop.  The answer seems to have assumed `Option Explicit` was not active.  See SomeGuy's answer below.

Comment: tested this on my own site's url and it worked fine. Tested on stackoverflow.com and I got an 'access is denied' error

Answer (score 0):

Specify an actual address in place of *alink* or define *alink* as a variable which contains a web address.

Answer (score 0):

variable definitions missing, URL to working code below

```
Dim alink As Hyperlink
Dim strURL As String
Dim objhttp As Object
```

[Bulk Url checker macro excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644789/bulk-url-checker-macro-excel)

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer not an answer itself as it does not answer the question clearly enough, although the answer is in the link. Write it up! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the suggested code above. I had to adapt it further so that it can differentiate between a URL and a File as I have both in my excel spreadsheet. It works well for my particular spreadsheet with about 50 links to files and URLs.

```
Sub Audit_WorkSheet_For_Broken_Links()

If MsgBox("Is the Active Sheet a Sheet with Hyperlinks You Would Like to Check?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then

    Exit Sub

End If

Dim alink As Hyperlink
Dim strURL As String
Dim objhttp As Object
Dim count As Integer

On Error Resume Next
count = 0                                       'used to track the number of non-working links
For Each alink In Cells.Hyperlinks
    strURL = alink.Address

    If Left(strURL, 4) <> "http" Then
        strURL = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Hyperlink Base") & strURL
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = "Testing Link: " & strURL
    Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objhttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
    objhttp.Send
    If objhttp.statustext = "OK" Then               'if url does exist
        alink.Parent.Interior.ColorIndex = 0        'clear cell color formatting
    ElseIf objhttp.statustext <> "OK" Then          'if url doesn't exist
        If Dir(strURL) = "" Then                    'check if the file exists
            alink.Parent.Interior.Color = 255       'set cell background to red its not a valid file or URL
            count = count + 1                       'update the count of bad cell links
        Else
            alink.Parent.Interior.ColorIndex = 0    'clear cell color formatting
        End If
    End If

Next alink
Application.StatusBar = False

'Release objects to prevent memory issues
Set alink = Nothing
Set objhttp = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox ("Checking Complete!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & count & " Cell(s) With Broken or Suspect Links. Errors are Highlighted in RED.")

End Sub
```

I hope this helps someone else as much as it has helped me... A little better everyday!