# Bulk Url checker macro excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Im seeking for help as i have a bulk of links to check if the link is broken i have tried the below macro but it works twice and after that it is no longer working i am using ms office 10 64bit i would like to add on the macro if macro 
can check the image resolution for example if i paste url on column A it will highlight the broken links and on column b it will show the image resolution

```
Sub Audit_WorkSheet_For_Broken_Links()

If MsgBox("Is the Active Sheet a Sheet with Hyperlinks You Would Like to Check?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then

    Exit Sub

End If

On Error Resume Next
For Each alink In Cells.Hyperlinks
    strURL = alink.Address

    If Left(strURL, 4) <> "http" Then
        strURL = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Hyperlink Base") & strURL
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = "Testing Link: " & strURL
    Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objhttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
    objhttp.Send

    If objhttp.statustext <> "OK" Then

        alink.Parent.Interior.Color = 255
    End If

Next alink
Application.StatusBar = False
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox ("Checking Complete!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Cells With Broken or Suspect Links are Highlighted in RED.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure you won't get the resolution (do you mean dimensions?) from a HEAD request.

Comment: When you say it works twice, do you mean it works only twice ever? Or, if you quit and reopen Excel, can you run the macro again?

Comment: it's fine with me if i won't get the resolution,,my next task is to remove dead links please help i want this macro to highlight deadlink

Comment: yes it works only twice and never work again i have shared also with my colleague but this is not reliable ,even i quit and run again it will no longer work

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line to see if any errors are being generated

Comment: Edited my answer to provide another potential solution. Give it a try and let me know how you fare.

Comment: @ Nick Peranzi i don't know what to do right now still not highlighting the deadlink, im using windows 8.1 excel 2013...im not getting any error but not working

Comment: Can you post your source data file? I tested my example below and it works but seems to give you trouble; I'm thinking it may be a quirk in your data that I didn't take into account.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I changed your macro to declare variables properly and release objects upon macro completion; this should address any potential memory issues. Please try this code and let me know if it works.

```
Sub Audit_WorkSheet_For_Broken_Links()

If MsgBox("Is the Active Sheet a Sheet with Hyperlinks You Would Like to Check?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then

    Exit Sub

End If

Dim alink As Hyperlink
Dim strURL As String
Dim objhttp As Object

On Error Resume Next
For Each alink In Cells.Hyperlinks
    strURL = alink.Address

    If Left(strURL, 4) <> "http" Then
        strURL = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Hyperlink Base") & strURL
    End If

    Application.StatusBar = "Testing Link: " & strURL
    Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objhttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
    objhttp.Send

    If objhttp.statustext <> "OK" Then

        alink.Parent.Interior.Color = 255
    End If

Next alink
Application.StatusBar = False

'Release objects to prevent memory issues
Set alink = Nothing
Set objhttp = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox ("Checking Complete!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Cells With Broken or Suspect Links are Highlighted in RED.")

End Sub
```

**Old Answer Below**

Combining your macro (which seems to be from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256522/checking-for-broken-hyperlinks-in-excel)) with an alternative found on [excelforum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/760760-checking-for-broken-hyperlinks.html) yields the below code. Give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

```
Sub TestHLinkValidity()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim fsoFSO As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim cCell As Range

If MsgBox("Is the Active Sheet a Sheet with Hyperlinks You Would Like to Check?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then

    Exit Sub

End If

Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
For Each cCell In rRng.Cells
    If cCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        strPath = GetHlinkAddr(cCell)
        If fsoFSO.FileExists(strPath) = False Then cCell.Interior.Color = 65535
   End If
Next cCell
End Sub

Function GetHlinkAddr(rngHlinkCell As Range)
    GetHlinkAddr = rngHlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

Comment: sorry it's not working for me----Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Comment: @cath are you getting an error? What OS and version of Excel are you running? I just tested this on Windows 10, Excel 2013 and get no errors.

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 and excel 2013

Comment: actually im not getting any error but it's just not working it is not highlighting the dead link