# Excel VBA: get error code for invalid URL in hyperlink with WinHttpRequest

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, hyperlink, request

In Excel, I have a list with URLs. I need to check if IE (default browser) can open these. They don't have to open actually, it's to check the accessibility.
If they can't open, I need to isolate the error-code and place that in another column.

After searching around here, I started with following the hyperlinks, and used GET to get the data in a `MsgBox`. This seems to work partially, but of course now I get the `MsgBox` with every URL also without error. Also I'm looking for a way to extract the error and place that in the active sheet.

What I've got so far:

```
Sub Request_Data()

' declare
numRow = 2
Dim MyRequest As Object

' activate URLs without Follow
Do While ActiveSheet.Range("C" & numRow).Hyperlinks.Count > 0
numRow = numRow + 1

' create request
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", _
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & numRow)

' send request
MyRequest.Send

' outcome
MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText

' isolate the error code (for example 404)
' place error code in excel sheet in column H next to row URL
Loop

End Sub
```

Does someone know how I should proceed?
I thought this might be useful but I don't know where to start.
[Checking for broken hyperlinks in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256522/checking-for-broken-hyperlinks-in-excel)
and 
[Bulk Url checker macro excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644789/bulk-url-checker-macro-excel)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the code below - you will need to adapt the `Test` sub-routine to loop through your cells and call `IsValidUrl` for each value you want to test:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    MsgBox IsValidUrl("http://www.thisdoesnotexistxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/")
    MsgBox IsValidUrl("http://www.google.com/")
    MsgBox IsValidUrl("http://www.ppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrr.com/")
End Sub

Function IsValidUrl(strUrl As String) As Long

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim lngCode As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl
        .Send
        lngCode = 0
    End With

    GoTo ExitHandler

ErrHandler:
    lngCode = Err.Number

ExitHandler:
    Set objRequest = Nothing
    IsValidUrl = lngCode

End Function
```

My output is:

```
-2147012889 
 0 
-2147012889
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your answer. Is it possible that I couldn't run your example before adapting it? When I try to run it, I don't get any outcome.

Comment: I'm working in Excel 2016 (64bit) by the way. After adapting it and giving my range in stead of your examples, I came across Runtime-error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error).

Comment: It ran for me just in a module with no other code. Excel 2013 32 bit

Comment: Just tried it again in a blank module without adapting anything. If I try to run it I get the messagebox 'Macros' with the option to run 'test'. But no outcome appears.

Comment: Did you have the Immediate Window open in your VBA editor? I've updated the code to also provide `MsgBox` output in case you're not monitoring the Immediate Window.

Comment: Hi Robin, I wasn't monitoring that so now it makes sense. I get the same output as you now, but when trying to get the function to work on my range, it doesn't give any output. No errors though.

Comment: Well maybe you should post some of the URLs that you are trying to process. Otherwise good luck :)