# Check and fix broken links in excel to other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am new to VBA and to this Forum.

So I have a workbook that copy's data from other workbooks using active links (So I can refresh the worksheet and get updated values) and have the hyperlink (for a copied workbook) pasted in one of the columns. I want to be able to check if the links are broken and repair them. So I added a refresh button to keep the values updated and ErrorHandler to the sub but am unsure how to get excel to identify/store which row has the broken link and paste the new link to the file. Is this possible and how would I do it.

If that is not possible, is it possible to identify the broken hyperlinks (the column that has the pasted hyperlinks). I found this forum but am unsure how to change it so it checks excel files? [Checking for broken hyperlinks in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256522/checking-for-broken-hyperlinks-in-excel)

```
     '///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'
'This code refreshes all links in the active worksheet.
'
'///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Sub RefreshAllLinks()

'Minimize runtime
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Initialize Variables
Dim summarywb As Workbook

'Set initial values
Set summarywb = ThisWorkbook

'Refresh all linked data on the active worksheet
summarywb.ActiveSheet.Activate
'On Error GoTo HRepair
summarywb.UpdateLink Name:=summarywb.LinkSources

HRepair:
Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    Set cl = ActiveCell
    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            ' Add Hyperlinks
            cl.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=cl, Address:=.SelectedItems(lngCount), _
                TextToDisplay:=.SelectedItems(lngCount)
        Next lngCount
    End With

'Display back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found this code online and changed it up for my purposes. You can get it to check all the different case you want for the links. I add a prompt to re-link the file if broken.

Hope this helps everyone!

```
Sub GetLinkStatus()
    Dim avLinks As Variant
    Dim nIndex As Integer
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim nStatus As Integer
    Dim sLink As String

    avLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(XlLink.xlExcelLinks)
    If IsEmpty(avLinks) Then
        GetLinkStatus1 = "No links in workbook."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For nIndex = 1 To UBound(avLinks)
        sLink = avLinks(nIndex)
        sLink = Right(sLink, Len(sLink) - InStrRev(sLink, "\"))
        nStatus = ActiveWorkbook.LinkInfo(sLink, xlLinkInfoStatus)
        Select Case nStatus
                Case xlLinkStatusCopiedValues    ' Copied Values = 10
                    sResult = "Copied values"
                Case xlLinkStatusIndeterminate   ' Unable to determine status = 5
                    sResult = "Indeterminate"
                Case xlLinkStatusInvalidName     ' Invalid Name = 7
                    sResult = "Invalid name"
                Case xlLinkStatusMissingFile     ' File Missing = 1
                    sResult = "Missing file"
                Case xlLinkStatusMissingSheet    ' Sheet Missing = 2
                    sResult = "Missing sheet"
                Case xlLinkStatusNotStarted      ' Not Started = 6
                    sResult = "Not started"
                Case xlLinkStatusOK              ' No Errors = 0
                    sResult = "OK"
                Case xlLinkStatusOld            ' Status may be out of date = 3
                    sResult = "Old"
                Case xlLinkStatusSourceNotCalculated    ' Not yet calculated = 4
                    sResult = "Source not calculated"
                Case xlLinkStatusSourceNotOpen          ' Not open = 8
                    sResult = "Source not open"
                Case xlLinkStatusSourceOpen             ' Source document is open = 9
                    sResult = "Source open"
                Case Else
                    sResult = "Unknown status code"
            End Select
        If nStatus <> 0 And nStatus <> 3 Then ' Checking for Case No Errors and Status may be out of date
            ActiveSheet.Range("D1") = nStatus ' To check error
            MsgBox avLinks(nIndex) & " - the link is broken. Choose new destiation"
cf:
            f = Application.GetOpenFilename()
            If f <> "" Then
                ' Updating the "LINK"
                n = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row
                For Each lnk In ActiveSheet.Range("U9:U" & n).Hyperlinks
                    GetAddress = lnk.Address
                    GetAddress = Right(GetAddress, Len(GetAddress) - InStrRev(GetAddress, "\"))
                    If InStr(avLinks(nIndex), GetAddress) <> 0 Then
                        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(lnk.Range.Row, 21), Address:=f, TextToDisplay:="Link"
                    End If
                Next

                ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink avLinks(nIndex), f, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            Else
                GoTo cf
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

See if the following will help you:

[Check if URL exists](http://sam308.com/check-if-url-exists)

[Fix Hyperlinks](http://sam308.com/fix-hyperlinks)