# Force formatting with URL in cell

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to make it where the user enters a URL into a merged cell ("F22:I22") it automatically formats it to be a URL/hyperlink. So if someone enters `google.com` it would make it `https://www.google.com/` and validate it.

I have. (which I'm almost positive this is wrong)

```
Sub formaturl () 
    if ishyperlink(value) then values (x,y) = format(value, "https:// .com")
End Sub
```

I've seen code where you can add the hyperlinks to a cell with a drop down. This is not what I want since the user will be adding their company URL.

EDIT: this is the final code that i was able to get to work. I also modified the "hyperlinks" cell style to be the Arial size 16 font with no underline to make it easier to read.

```
Sub handlethingone(target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim prefixAddress As String
    Dim suffixAddress As String

    Set xCell = ActiveSheet.Range("F22")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    prefixAddress = "www."
    suffixAddress = ".com"

    With ws
       If .Range("F22").Value <> vbNullString Then
            If Not Left(.Range("F22").Value, 4) = prefixAddress Then
                xCell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                prefixAddress & xCell, TextToDisplay:=prefixAddress & xCell
            End If
            If Not Right(.Range("F22").Value, 4) = suffixAddress Then
                xCell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                xCell & suffixAddress, TextToDisplay:=xCell & suffixAddress
            End If
        End If
    End With
  With xCell.Font
        .Name = ("Arial")
        .Size = 16
        .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With

    With xCell.Font
        .Name = ("Arial")
        .Size = 16
        .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: No, I had a different question, figured it out, and then had this question but forgot to change the title.. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Are you only doing this for one cell or multiple? Because there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: The range provided is a merged cell. This would be the only spot in the worksheet that would use it.

Comment: How will you know if the URL is https?

Comment: I don't, if it's easier to go http thats fine too. If its even easier just to do the www.somelink.com I'm ok with that as well.

Comment: The validation portion is slightly more difficult. You may be able to use the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256522/checking-for-broken-hyperlinks-in-excel). Otherwise, I think you can just use the Worksheet Change event to add the hyperlink.

Comment: Worksheet change event?

Comment: Yes, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something as shown here:

```
Option Explicit
Sub HyperlinkFormatter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim prefixAddress As String
    Dim suffixAddress As String
    
    Set xCell = ActiveSheet.Range("F22")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    prefixAddress = "www."
    suffixAddress = ".com"
    
    With ws
       If .Range("F22").value <> vbNullString Then
            If Not Left(.Range("F22").value, 4) = prefixAddress Then
                xCell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, address:="", SubAddress:= _
                prefixAddress & xCell, TextToDisplay:=prefixAddress & xCell
            End If
            If Not Right(.Range("F22").value, 4) = suffixAddress Then
                xCell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, address:="", SubAddress:= _
                xCell & suffixAddress, TextToDisplay:=xCell & suffixAddress
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
    With xCell.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With

    With xCell.Font
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Color = -4155132
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I need this to work when the cell F22 has data in it and they enter or move to a different cell. and To formatt with the www. if it's not entered.

Comment: this isn't updating anything.




`Private Sub URL_change(ByVal target As Range)
 Dim xCell As Range

    Set xCell = ActiveSheet.Range("F22")

    xCell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "SUPPLIER!F22", TextToDisplay:="Address"

    With xCell.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With

    With xCell.Font
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        .Color = -4155132
    End With

End Sub`