# Deadlinks or url checker using macro excel

Tags: excel, vba

Please need help, I am trying to search for a formula or macro formula for checking links for example if i paste a link on the entire column a and column c then the result will show on column b and d."YES" if the link is existing then "NO" if the links is not exist

Comment: Are you talking about internet links such as www.stackoverflow.com or are you talking about file links such as C:\YourFolder\YourFIle.xls or maybe intranet files such as //YourIntranet/YourSite/YourFile.pdf or maybe even only links within a file from one sheet to another?

Comment: @ Ralph I am talking about images link please check the samples below http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81I2yVZ25LL._UX695_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81jY-fVj4cL._UX695_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81LEfaH%2BeML._UY695_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81LEfaH%2BeML._UY695_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81I2yVZ2L._UX695_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81jY-fVj4L._UX695_.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort dead hyperlinks in Excel with VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118221/sort-dead-hyperlinks-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: the answer is not working for me i don't have idea for First add a reference to Microsoft XML V3 (or above), using Tools->References. Then paste this code:

Comment: Here you can read and learn how to add a reference in the VBE: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx