# Detecting if file exists in SharePoint via MicrosoftXML

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, excel-2016

I have this VBA-function, which I've cobbled together from googling how to check if a SharePoint-file exists using VBA. In the end most of the code I'm using is coming from [this post](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/570437-macro-check-if-file-exists-sharepoint.html), which again borrows its method [from a SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118221/sort-dead-hyperlinks-in-excel-with-vba).

As I am not overly familiar working with SharePoint (or urls in general) in VBA, I wonder if there is any way this function can give a false positive, i.e. claim a file exists which does not. Or vice versa, I suppose.

```
Function sharepointFileExists(ByVal strUrl As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.Send
    Debug.Print oHttp.Status & " " & oHttp.statusText
    sharepointFileExists = True
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
    sharepointFileExists = False
End Function
```

I've tried some obvious things, like giving the path to a folder instead of a file, or to a file on a local drive, both of which gave satisfactory results.

However, I am as I said unfamiliar with working with networks in VBA, so if I am overlooking any ways in which this function can fail me, I would very much like to know. Can I e.g. get statuses which won't throw an error, but which will mean that no file exists at the specified path?