# Bulk check the status of an hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, reference, http-status-code-403

I have a long list of hyperlinks on excel and would like to create a code that checks on the selection whether those links drive to an error page or not.

I adapted the code from this post [Sort dead hyperlinks in Excel with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118221/sort-dead-hyperlinks-in-excel-with-vba)

However, each time I run it the error

> "403 - Forbidden"

appears, no matter if the link works or not.

What I would like the code to do is write in the next cell leads to a 404 page or not.
I guess the problem is the lack of an extra line authorising excel to follow the hyperlink, but I can't think on how to solve this.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub CheckHyperlinks()    
    Dim oColumn As Range

    Dim oCell As Range
    For Each oCell In Selection    
        If oCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then   
            Dim oHyperlink As Hyperlink
            Set oHyperlink = oCell.Hyperlinks(1) ' I assume only 1 hyperlink per cell

            Dim strResult As String
            strResult = GetResult(oHyperlink.Address)
            oCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strResult
        End If
    Next oCell
End Sub

Private Function GetResult(ByVal strUrl As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.send

    GetResult = oHttp.Status & " " & oHttp.statusText

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    GetResult = "Error: " & Err.Description  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs for example if you try to access `http://www.google.com` but it works on `https://www.google.com` (you can test it with `Debug.Print GetResult("https://www.google.com"` where you get `200 OK` as result)

So it obviously doesn't follow the redirects for the `http://` to `https://` that Google has set.

Alternatively use the [WinHttpRequest object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinHttp/winhttprequest) as follows instead of `GetResult`:

```
Private Function GetResultExtended(ByVal strUrl As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim xhr As Object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    xhr.Option(6) = True 'follow redirects
    xhr.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    xhr.send

    GetResultExtended = xhr.Status & " " & xhr.statusText
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    GetResultExtended = "Error: " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Instead of `xhr.Option(6)` you could also use `xhr.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects)` if you define the following [WinHttpRequestOption enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinHttp/winhttprequestoption) above your function:

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum WinHttpRequestOption
    WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString
    WinHttpRequestOption_URL
    WinHttpRequestOption_URLCodePage
    WinHttpRequestOption_EscapePercentInURL
    WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags
    WinHttpRequestOption_SelectCertificate
    WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects
    WinHttpRequestOption_UrlEscapeDisable
    WinHttpRequestOption_UrlEscapeDisableQuery
    WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols
    WinHttpRequestOption_EnableTracing
    WinHttpRequestOption_RevertImpersonationOverSsl
    WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttpsToHttpRedirects
    WinHttpRequestOption_EnablePassportAuthentication
    WinHttpRequestOption_MaxAutomaticRedirects
    WinHttpRequestOption_MaxResponseHeaderSize
    WinHttpRequestOption_MaxResponseDrainSize
    WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttp1_1
    WinHttpRequestOption_EnableCertificateRevocationCheck
End Enum
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I changed the function for yours, and it still appears the same problem. I'm trying with an URL that leads to a 404 page (http://www.nisbets.ie/dualit-black-kettle/cc804?vatToggle=incvat) and one that works (https://www.nisbets.ie/dualit-bread-toaster-6-slice-stainless-steel/e972?vatToggle=incvat) but in both cases in the cell near them appears "403 Forbidden".

Comment: @Paula Change `xhr.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False` to `xhr.Open "GET", strUrl, False`

Comment: Thanks! Is it working now :) Only pitty is that it takes a lot of time to run on long lists of hyperlinks, but I guess I have to be patient! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Paula Of course it takes time because it has to wait for every website to send an answer and VBA does not support multi threadding, so each URL is checked one after the other (parrallel checking would only work with multiple threads, but therefore you would need to to it with something else than Excel).